# Adding multiple events to a PDF report

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf report program using FPDF that will have three inputs, the report date, the event date and the event description.

The problem is that I created a while loop in case the person decides to add more than one event, but the PDF will always show just the last event. Can anyone help me to see how I can keep adding the events to the PDF?

```
from fpdf import FPDF

date = input("Type the date (mm/yyy) for your report: ")

while True:

    date_event = input("Type the date of the event (dd/mm/yyy): ")
    event_description = input("Describe the event: ")

    cont = input("To add another event type 1, to generate PDF type 2: ")
    if cont == "2":
        break
    if cont == "1":
        continue


pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=16)
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Report for " + date, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.set_line_width(1)
pdf.set_draw_color(255, 150, 150)
pdf.line(20, 20, 195, 20)
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.multi_cell(0, 15, txt=date_event, align="L")
pdf.multi_cell(0, 8, txt=event_description, align="L")
pdf.output("report.pdf")
```

I want to add event1, event2, event3 and so on to the report, but with this code, it just adds the last event that I type.